# Searching for a better Twitter widget

Tags: widgets, twitter

I'm using the "FriendFeed Activity" widget to show the latest 7 enties of my friend feed. However, FriendFeed just aggregates my Twitter, Blog (via RSS) and YouTube activities. That are things Twitter couldn't handle at the beginning, but now can.

So I'm thinking of removing my FriendFeed and switch completely to Twitter (and a Twitter widget). But the "FriendFeed Activity" widget shows an Icon in front of every post (YouTube symbol, RSS symbol, Twitter symbol) and it displays a thumbnail if there's a YouTube link in the post.

Is there a Twitter widget, that has this functionality, too? Maybe even recognizes more / resolves bit.ly Links ...?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this will give you everything you're looking for, but I like [Twitter Tools](http://alexking.org/projects/wordpress) by Alex King.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't fulfill my requirements (symbols, thumbnail, complete url)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try [Twitter Widget Pro](http://xavisys.com/wordpress-plugins/wordpress-twitter-widget/) as a "proper" standalone Twitter widget and find similar dedicated widgets for RSS and FriendFeed? Doing it like that will probably yield widgets of higher quality if you can stand the extra clutter.

Comment: Couldn't find many screenshots, but it doesn't look like it's fulfilling any of my requirements ...